# Updating to Xcode 10 made value wrapped with "Optional()"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

So recently I **switch from Xcode 9 to Xcode 10** for my iOS app development. the first thing I noticed that when I tried to print out a variable, the **value is wrapped with optional**, while **in Xcode 9 it never happened**. for example here is the code that I test.

```
let version = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
let build = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleVersionKey as String) as! String
let parameters = ["branch_id": loginData.profile.branchId, 
                  "version": "\(version).\(build)", 
                  "os_name" : "ios", 
                  "user_id" : loginData.uid]
print(parameters)
```

and the output was like :

> ["os_name": "ios", 
>   "branch_id": Optional("2"), "version": "1.5.8.3",
>   "user_id": Optional("1141")]

I've tried to force unwrap the code with exclamation mark

`"branch_id": loginData.profile.branchId!`,

or even better with coalescing operator

`"branch_id": loginData.profile.branchId ?? "0"`

It works, but I have like, 30+ lines of code with the same problem, do I need to do it one by one? Or is there a way to change this behaviour?

FYI I'm using Swift 4 for my project.
Edit : FYI this was tested on iOS 12, while before in Xcode 9 was tested in iOS 11

Edit:

To answer [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) comment asking info about where `loginData.profile.branchId` come from, here it is.

So, the data is fetched from **data model**, and I use this code to fetch it:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")
let fetchResults = try context.fetch(request) as? [NSManagedObject]
let loginData = fetchResults![0]
let profile = loginData.value(forKey: "profile") as! NSManagedObject
self.profile = Profile()
self.profile.branchId = profile.value(forKey: "branchId") as? String
```

Comment: It seems like the "loginData" is itself an optional OR it contains objects which are optional. Try wrapping it before accessing any object/variable from it. Hope it helps!!

Comment: You have not given any info about `loginData.profile.branchId`. But that is what the question is about!

Comment: @matt thanks for your comment, I've updated my question, please check, thanks.

Comment: Do you think `profile.value(forKey: "branchId") as? String ?? ""` would work? edit: nope it doesn't work

Comment: You can avoid those issues if you care more for the design. In a Core Data environment you know the data model and you are supposed to know which attributes are optional. If an attribute has always a value declare the property as non-optional.  Even assigning a default value in `awakeFromInsert()` is safer and more convenient than optionals. And use `NSManagedObject` subclasses to take advantage of dot notation and distinct types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using **coalescing operator** which is `?? ""` and implemented it my code like:

```
var parameters = [String: Any]()
if loginData.profile != nil {
    if loginData.profile.branchId != "" {
        let version = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
        let build = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleVersionKey as String) as! String
        parameters = ["branch_id": loginData.profile.branchId ?? "", 
                      "version" : "\(version).\(build)", 
                      "os_name" : "ios", 
                      "user_id" : loginData.uid ?? ""
                      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use Optional Unwrapping with if-let statement

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")
        if let fetchResults = try context.fetch(request) as? [NSManagedObject]{
            let loginData = fetchResults[0]
            let profile = loginData.value(forKey: "profile") as! NSManagedObject
            self.profile = Profile()
            if let branchId = profile.value(forKey: "branchId") as? String{
                self.profile.branchId = branchId
            }
        }

if let version = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String, let build = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleVersionKey as String) as? String{
            let branchId = loginData.profile.branchId ?? ""
            let branchId = loginData.uid ?? ""
            let parameters = ["branch_id": branchId,
                              "version": "\(version).\(build)",
                "os_name" : "ios",
                "user_id" : login_tty.uid]
            print(parameters)
        }
```

> Never use force unwrapping, i mean ! directly, it may result in crash,
>   instead safely unwrap using `if let` and `guard let`

Comment: Please don't say *never*. There is more than black and white. For example the values for `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `kCFBundleVersionKey` can be safely forced unwrapped because **you** clearly know that the keys exist and info.plist cannot be changed at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

if you are printing an optional value Xcode prints the value warapped with the word optional("value").

if you want to avoid this you must upwarapped the value. 
you have 3 ways to do that:

1. the careful way, use guard let or if let:

   ```
   if let branchId = profile.value(forKey: "branchId") as? String {
         //here branchId != nil
     }

     guard let branchId = profile.value(forKey: "branchId") as? String else { return }
   ```
2. the force unwarapped way:

   let branchId = profile.value(forKey: "branchId") as! String

on that way, if the value is nil the app will crash so be careful

3. use default value:

   let branchId = profile.value(forKey: "branchId") as? String ?? "default value"